# MSSQL dose not return data for all fields

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a procedure in which i will send the table name to fetch all records from it..so that i don't have to create different procedure...but i am facing some problem in that.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTableData] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@tableName Varchar(100),
@whrFldName NVarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--  Insert statements for procedure here

DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' WHERE ' + 
                       @whrFldName + ' = ''y'' ;'
--PRINT @sql
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

The PHP code is this..

```
$sql ="EXEC [dbo].[getTableData] 'tbl_services','serviceStatus'";
$rst = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
$i = 0;
while($result = odbc_fetch_array($rst))
{
    $returnPageData[$i] = $result;
    $i++;
}
```

It executes just fine in server but when I call it from my **PHP** code, it returns null.

Here if I remove `*` and place fields it works fine..I have tested my code well,it specially creates the problem for a **Text** type field..

If i change the procedure to this,it works fine..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTableData]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@rowsPerPage as bigint,
@pageNum as bigint
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH SQLPaging AS   ( 
    SELECT TOP(@rowsPerPage * @pageNum) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY creationDate DESC) 
    AS resultNum, * 
    FROM [DB_SB].[dbo].[tbl_blog] )
SELECT 
    blogTitle,
    blogSlug,
    blogImage,
    substring( blogContent, 1, 210 ) AS blogContent,
    creationDate,
    blogAddedBy

 FROM SQLPaging WITH (nolock) WHERE resultNum > ((@pageNum - 1) * @rowsPerPage)
```

END

But this is no logical..if i send fields everytime..this is not what i want exactly..

Any solution??please help...

Comment: Can you show us ur php code?

Comment: Sure...

$sql ="EXEC [dbo].[getTableData] 'tbl_services','serviceStatus'";
 $rst = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
 $i = 0;
 while($result = odbc_fetch_array($rst))
 {
  $returnPageData[$i] = $result;
  $i++;
 }

Comment: Can you update that code in your question? So everyone can refer it

Comment: please refer me if m wrong anywhere..

Comment: Have you defined connection string? like: $conn = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mssql_select_db('somedb', $conn);

Comment: yes i have..as i said in my post..it returns value if a call some selected fields..actually whats happening it can't fetch data for **TEXT** type field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL Server Profiler to see what’s actually getting to database engine.

If your stored procedure is executed correctly when run from SSMS then there is a problem somewhere in PHP part.

Are you using the same database using when testing from SSMS? There might be some issue in that…